# Doubt in identifications for a vector field in the product of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

The following is the Exercise 1) a), Chapter 6 from do Carmo, Riemannian Geometry:

1. Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be Riemannian manifolds and consider $M_1 \times M_2$ with the product metric. Let $\nabla^1$ and $\nabla^2$ be the Riemannian connection in $M^1$ and $M^2$, respectively.

a) Show the Riemannian connection $\nabla$ of $M_1 \times M_2$ is given by
$$\nabla_{X_1 + X_2}(Y_1 + Y_2) = \nabla^1_{X_1}Y_1 + \nabla^2_{X_2}Y_2,$$
where $X_1,Y_1 \in \mathcal{X}(M_1)$ and  $X_2,Y_2 \in \mathcal{X}(M_2)$.

Here are my doubts:

**Doubt 1)** I'm trying to understand what exactly means, for example, the sum $X_1 + X_2$. Is it just a notation for $(X_1, X_2) \in \mathcal{X}(M_1) \times \mathcal{X}(M_2)$?

**Doubt 2)** Given $p = (p_1,p_2) \in M_1 \times M_2$, it's really commum to identify
$$T_{p}(M_1 \times M_2) \equiv T_{p_1}M_1 \oplus T_{p_2}M_2.$$
Again, the meaning of the last direct sum is just $T_{p_1}M_1 \times T_{p_2}M_2$ ? In this case, the identification would be
$$L : T_{p}(M_1 \times M_2)  \rightarrow T_{p_1}M_1 \times T_{p_2}M_2$$
defined by $L(w) = (\alpha_1'(0), \alpha_2'(0)),$ where $w \in T_{p}(M_1\times M_2)$ is given by $w = c'(0)$, for $c(t) = (\alpha_1(t), \alpha_2(t))$ with $\alpha_1 : I \rightarrow M_1$ and $\alpha_2 : I \rightarrow M_2$? In this case, using the natural structure for the product $M_1\times M_2$ and the map $L$, I conclude that a basis for $T_{p_1}M_1 \times T_{p_2}M_2$ would be:
$$\{\partial_1, ...,\partial_{n}, \partial_{n+1}, ..., \partial_{n+m}\},$$
where $\partial_i = (\partial^1_i,0)$, for $i = 1, ..., n$ and $\partial_i = (0, \partial^2_i)$, for $i = n+1, ..., n+m$ [here $\partial^1_i$ and $\partial^2_i$ are tangent vector of the basis of $T_{p_1}M_1$ and $T_{p_2} M_2$ respectively].

**Doubt 3)** In item a) above, I believe the author is using the identification
"a tangent fild in $\mathcal{X} (M_1\times M_2)$ is given by $(X_1, X_2).$ In this case, what would mean $(X_1, X_2)(f),$ for $f \in C^{\infty}(M_1 \times M_2)$? What would be its expression on a local coordinate system of $M_1 \times M_2$ ? **(I tried this using the basis I wrote in Doubt 2.)**

**Doubt 4)**  What's the exactly relation between $\mathcal{X}(M_1\times M_2)$ and $\mathcal{X}(M_1) \times \mathcal{X}(M_2)$ ?

**What a tried for item a)**:

In general, given a Riemannian manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, it's Levi-Civita connection is given by:
$$\nabla_{X}Y = \sum_{k=1}^n(X(b_k) + \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{i} b_{j} \Gamma_{ij}^k)\partial_k,$$
where, in coordenates, $X = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \partial_i$ and $Y = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \partial_j$. I tried to go from this formula and use all the things I said in the Doubts. But I always get stuck when involves the functions in $C^{\infty}(M_1 \times M_2)$. Something seems not to fit. Anyone may help me ?

Comment: For 1) and 2), you are right. The direct sum of two vector spaces is isomorphic to their product. The notation $X_1 + X_2$ should be rigorously $(X_1,0)+ (0,X_2)$, but we canonically identify a vector field $X_1$ on $M$ with the vector field $(X_1,0)$ on $M\times N$, etc. For 3), if $(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ are coordinates on $M$ and $(y^1,\ldots,y^k)$ on $N$, then $X_1 = X_1^i\partial_{x^i}$ and $X_2 = X^j_2\partial_{y^j}$, and $(X_1,X_2)f = X^i_1 \partial_{x^i}f + X_2^j \partial_{y^j}f$ (recall that $(x^1,\ldots,x^n,y^1,\ldots,y^k)$ are coordinates on $M\times N$.)

Comment: Thank you very much Didier!

Comment: Just one more question: For example, given $f \in C^{\infty}(M_{1}\times M_{2})$, we have $\partial_{x^{i}}f \equiv (f \circ c)'(0)$, with $c(t) = (\alpha^{1}_i(t), 0)$ being a curve  in $M_1 \times M_2$, where $\alpha^{1}_{i}(t) = \varphi(\tilde{p_1} + e_it)$ ? [here $\varphi$ is a local coordinate of $M_1$ around $p_1$ and $\tilde{p} = \varphi^{-1}(p_1)$]

Comment: You must be confused with the notion of exterior direct sum, and interior direct sum, Munkres topology book has a very nice explaination of those concept see Chapter 11 first section